# Swift 3 - Is there any way to force method call on object?

Tags: swift, methods, swift3, call

I make simple API Manager. The way to do request is:

```
ApiManager
.get("method_name")
.parameters(["xxx" : "yyy"])
.requireAuth(true)
.request(success: success, failure: failure)
```

where:

`.get("people/1/")` - this static method that returns ApiManager object

`.request(success: success, failure: failure)` - this method starts request

I wonder if it is possible to force call those two methods in Swift 3?
Is there any way to prevent call to initializer of ApiManager?

**EDIT**

Thanks for your answers.
I edited my class and now API request looks that:

```
ApiManager(method: .get, action: "people/1/")
.parameters(["xxx" : "yyy"])
.requireAuth(true)
.request(success: success, failure: failure)
```

And I made my init as private to:

```
private init() {}
```

Comment: Seems that your functions are class functions and there is no call to initialiser of ApiManager. (It would've been `ApiManager()`). What do you mean by "force call"? Are they not getting called?

Comment: Actually my method .get("xxx") was static method with init inside and it returned object of ApiManager. 
"force call" - I mean I wanted to notify programmer that he must call method .get().
Anyway, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class ApiManager {
    private init(){

    }
}
```